# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT not working properly in Oreo

Tags: android

I am using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT,with Android N it was working fine. When I used to click on the start point and used to move to other activities,after pressing HOME if I used to click again on start point it used to take me back to that activity where I last left it, but with Android O everytime its getting started with root activity. Is any change done with its behaviour?

Comment: [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)

Comment: @AnoopM Its not containing any information w.r.t that